# combining a method to hide or show content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how I can combine a hide function and show function into 1 toggle Function that either fades in content or fades it out, im guessing this argument would update the fade method:

This is my current effort of JS using jQuery from my object but is totally wrong:

```
toggleAlertOverlay: function (state) {
  var instance = this;
  if (state === hide) {
    instance.selector.fadeOut();
  }
  elseif(state === show) {
    instance.selector.fadeIn();
  }
},
toggleAlertOverlay(hide);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

> The .fadeToggle() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. When called on a visible element, the element's display style property is set to none once the opacity reaches 0, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

```
$(<element>).fadeToggle();
```

Where `<element>` is a valid selector ....

Answer (score 0):

```
var toggleState = 'none';
toggleAllertOverlay: function()
{
    if(toggleState == 'none')
    {
        $('#element').fadeIn();
        toggleState == 'showing';
    }
    else
    {
        $('#element').fadeOut();
        toggleState == 'none';
    }
}
```

is just a concept based on what you have. Note the variable outside of the function. Its outside so it doesn't get destroyed upon function complete. But aside from that, theres various other methods you can try if this doesn't suit you. Up to and including jQuery `toggle()`